# QWebEnginePage - how to get access to Media Session API?

Tags: qt, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

Web pages can expose Media Session API, it is using for lock screens notifications and also for changing playing status directly on the page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API

You can see what I mean by playing youtube video on Fire Fox or Chromium based browser and in console run:

`navigator.mediaSession.metadata`

Is it possible to retrieve such data in page loaded in `QWebEngineView` / `QWebEnginePage`? I want it back to the C++. Also, I want even more, I want to hook on this data and get notified when metadata changed or when `navigator.mediaSession.playbackState` changed